# How to unset the spam quarantine mailbox in Exchange Server 2019

Tags: exchange-server, exchange-server-2019

I followed the docs to set a mailbox to handle quarantined email:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/configure-quarantine-mailboxes?view=exchserver-2019

I used `Set-ContentFilterConfig -QuarantineMailbox spamQ@mydomain.com`

Now I don't want this and just want spam going to the individuals Junk E-Mail folder. I can't find how to remove this setting.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way you can disable quarantine

```
Set-ContentFilterConfig -SCLQuarantineEnabled $false
```

Comment: Please refrain from answering with code-only. Note that you are not only answering to the OP, but also to any future readers of the question. Thus, please edit the post to contain an explanation as to why this line of code works.